# UIWebView to Play Local and downloaded Video

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, nsbundle, avcam

I want to play downloaded video using UIWebview. I get webkiterrordomain code=204 error.
but if i play video from resources folder it run perfect.
    //from resources folder run perfect

```
NSString *tempurl = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"video.mp4"];
   //from downloaded file
 NSString *tempurl = downloaded path;
NSURL* urlLocation = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:tempurl];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlLocation]];
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Solution is here, you can play video in Embedded UIWebView.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

NSString *embedHTML = @"\
<html><head>\
<style type=\"text/css\">\
body {\
background-color: transparent;\
color: white;\
}\
</style>\
</head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
<embed id=\"yt\" src=\"http://www.businessfactors.de/bfcms/images/stories/videos/defaultscreenvideos.mp4\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-mp4\" \
width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
</body></html>";

webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 412.0)];

[webView setOpaque:NO];
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, webView.frame.size.width, webView.frame.size.height];
[webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

}

Answer (score 3):

`WebkitErrorDomain 204` just means that it would play the video on an `MPInlinePlayerController`. So you just have to ignore the error and the video will play.

Comment: Not sure if there's a better way to ignore this, but I did the following in the webView:didFailLoadWithError: method: `if (error.code == 204){ NSLog(@"%s: ignoring ERROR 204...", __FUNCTION__); [self webViewDidFinishLoad:webView];}`

Answer (score 0):

Generate an html. Embed your video in it. Include both the html and the video file in the project resources. Then load html from webview.

Answer (score -1):

For playing local video file, you can use MPMoviePlayerController.

```
- (void) playVideo:(NSString *) videoName {
if ([self.fileManager fileExistsAtPath:videoName]) {
    [self stopVideo];
    self.videoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoName]];
    [self.videoPlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 360)];
    CGAffineTransform t1;
    t1 = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0,1.0);
    self.videoPlayer.view.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeAffineTransform(t1);
    [self.view addSubview:self.videoPlayer.view];
    [self.videoPlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
    [self.videoPlayer setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
     object:self.videoPlayer];
    [self.videoPlayer play];
}
```

}

```
- (void)stopVideo {
if (self.videoPlayer) {
    if ([self.videoPlayer playbackState] == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying) {
        [self.videoPlayer stop];
    }
    [self.videoPlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
    self.videoPlayer = nil;
}
```

}

```
- (void) movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*) aNotification {
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [aNotification object];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 removeObserver:self
 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
 object:player];
[self.videoPlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
```

}

Comment: Using MPMoviePlayerController over UIWebView is better in many ways. Please take back your down vote when you know it. :)