# How to play Video file in the UIwebView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, video, uiwebview

I know how to load the documents in the WebView. `[webView loadRequest:urlRequest];`

But If i use the same code to open the Video files , the webView works odd . The WebView starts playing the video with PLAY button over the top. How to remove it ? Is there any other way to play the video in webview smoothly ?

Comment: Try This:

[UIWebView to Play Local and downloaded Video][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386156/uiwebview-to-play-local-and-downloaded-video

I think this will solve your problem

Comment: Thats cool, Can you tell me how to pass my NSString LocalFilePath into the embedHtml ??

Comment: Is it HTML5? If so does the <video> tag also have the controls attribute specified? If so remove them. If its your webpage and you're not using HTML5 you might want to consider moving to it for videos.